# javascript getElementsByTagName with asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to a question for javascript with asp.net.

There is a clear button and I try to change it as a javascript function.

I guess that asp.net doesn't work as the html and the getElementsByTagName doesn't recognize asp:TextBox, I think.

How I can work as the getElementsByTagName("asp:TextBox") to this code?

```
<script>
    function Clear() {
        document.getElementById('answers').className = "animated fadeOut";

        //getElementbyId is working fine.  
        //document.getElementById('txtName').value = "";
        //document.getElementById('txtAge').value = "";
        //document.getElementById('txtShoeSize').value = "";

        //how can I make it work with for iterator???            
        var text = document.getElementsByClassName('textinput').getElementsByTagName("asp:TextBox");
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
        {
            text[i].value = "";
        }
    }
</script>

    <div id="Wrapper">    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class ="row">
        <span class ="label"><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name: "></asp:Label></span>
        <span class ="textinput"><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></span>
    </div>

    <div class ="row">
        <span class ="label"><asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text="Age: "></asp:Label></span>
        <span class ="textinput"><asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></span>
    </div>

    <div class ="row">
        <span class ="label"><asp:Label ID="lblShoeSize" runat="server" Text="Shoe Size: "></asp:Label></span>
        <span class ="textinput"><asp:TextBox ID="txtShoeSize" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></span>
    </div>
```

Edit: Thanks Sam, jfriend00 for your advise. 
there is the button call from html.

I think I might be misunderstood the javascript. 
What I found that it might be document.getElementById('xxxx').getElementsByTagName('input');
not as a document.getElementsByClassName('xxxx').getElementsByTagName("input");
it is bit confusing.

Thanks

```
    <div class ="row">
        <span class="label"><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" width="70"/></span>
        <span class="textinput"><input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="Clear()"/></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: When you want to run JS on an ASP file, you have to look at what the actual generated HTML is when it gets to the browser because that's what the JS operates on.  View/Source in the browser is your friend here to see the actual HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`asp:TextBox` translate to an html `input` element. So the tag name is `input`, not asp:TextBox

And, you can find text boxes in client side by this syntax if you want.

```
var txtBox = document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientID %>');
```

And, another way is to make use of the `this` object in JavaScript. But, I need to know where you'll be calling the `Clear()` function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, was this helpful? If so please vote and accept it. Cheers!